# return response()->download(); display blank page

Tags: laravel-5

I have this code

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/gggusers.xlsx'));
```

in my controller. It executes without any problem but instead of triggering the browser to download the excel file, it just displays a blank white page. I'm positive the file name & location is correct, because if I just change the file name gggusers.xlsx to something else or I delete the file, Laravel will display this error

`The file "D:\web\speak\storage\app/files/gggusers.xlsx" does not exist`.

Comment: You need to pass relative path, can you please try accessing it from your url first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue happens because I put

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/gggusers.xlsx'));
```

in another function and call it from the function that's being loaded inside route, something like this:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->download();
    }

    public function download(){
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/gggusers.xlsx'));
    }
}
```

The code above will display a blank page. No errors. The function download is being called without any problem, but somehow after that it just display blank page.

If I just put the code

```
return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/gggusers.xlsx'));
```

inside `function index()`, the file will be downloaded.

Really appreciate it if someone can explain to me why. Is this some kind of a bug or somehow it's an intended behavior of PHP/Laravel. Wasted a few hours because of this issue.

Comment: Same problem, if you return the response()->download (response()->stream) in a function, you need to also return your function in your main controller method. 
So "$this->downloadFile()"; become "return $this->downloadFile();"

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I've just had the same problem and solved it. Your problem is that you are returning the response (the file) from `download()` to the calling function, `index()`, but you are not returning anything from `index()` back to the browser tab, hence the blank page.

```
public function download(){
        return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/gggusers.xlsx'));
}
```

Here you are returning the download file to the `index()` function, but in the `index()` function you don't return anything back to the browser. So changing this:

```
public function index(){
        $this->download();
}
```

To this:

```
public function index(){
        return $this->download();
}
```

will return the file to the browser tab as you'd expect it to.

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I had the same problem. My Model was returning Storage::disk('diskname')->download(...); but as that Model was being called from a Controller and the Controller didn't return any data, it was showing a blank page. I returned the file (the same I got from the Model) from the controller and it worked.